# Is it possible to send data from iPhone App to BT 2.0 & non MFI compliant device via Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, mfi

We have BC5 Module device. And we are developing an iPhone app to connect to it. We were able to discover the device but we couldn't connect and send data to the device. The device is neither BT4.0 nor MFI compliant.

Is there a way to connect and send data to this device?

I appreciate your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app can't connct to a non-MFi, BT2.1 device. If the device exposes a headset/hands free or A2DP profile then you can pair with it using systems settings and an app can access it using the av framework as an audio device but you cannot send/receive data